# prevent new line character from being read in literally to python script

Tags: python, bash, pipe

I have a string that I want to pass to a python script, e.g.

```
$printf "tas\nty\n"
```

yields

```
tas
ty
```

however when I pipe (e.g. `printf "tas\nty\n" | ./pumpkin.py`) where pumpkin.py is :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys 
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
print data
```

I get the output

```
['tas\n', 'ty\n']
```

How do I prevent the newline character from being read by python?

Answer (score 4):

You can strip all white spaces (at the beginning and in the end) using `strip` :

```
data = [s.strip() for s in sys.stdin.readlines()]
```

If you need to strip only `\n` in the end you can do:

```
data = [s.rstrip('\n') for s in sys.stdin.readlines()]
```

Or use `splitlines` method:

```
data = sys.stdin.read().splitlines()
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_splitlines.htm